# Use of setInterval

Tags: javascript

When we have a `tick` function

```
tick() {
    this.setState({
        date: new Date()
    });
}
```

why should we use something like,

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
}
```

and not just simply

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
}
```

I guess that we have some closure problem when I try the second variant. But can you please explain in detail what happens.

You can find the rest of the code [here](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/amqdNA?editors=0010).

Comment: because of different `this`. Last version you can use with a little trick `this.tick.bind(this)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause passing

```
setInterval(this.tick,1000)
```

behaves like:

```
 window.tick = this.tick;
setInterval(window.tick,1000);
```

So *this* inside tick is window, which hasnt a setState method.

---

Now the real answer:

In javascript the context ( aka *this* ) is determined when the function is called.

```
 a.b() // b called with context a
 c.d(); // d called with context c
 e();// e called with the default (window) context
```

So as the setInterval function looks like this ( actually its written in c, but thats another thing):

```
function setInterval(func, time, ...args){
  //await however
  func(...args);//context is window
}
```

you will always loose the context through setInterval. A workaround would be either *.bind*ing or using arrow functions, which always take their surrounding context ( so they have nothing to loose ;))

Comment: @bergi ok ok, ill add a bit more in depth explanation